# GreenSock Draggable: creating a spinner with momentum rotation

Tags: animation, gsap

I tried to copy the Spin demo from https://greensock.com/draggable but my spinner doesn't have the momentum from the demo:

http://codepen.io/tomsoderlund/pen/XjWvwO

Isn’t this use of `throwProps` enough?

```
Draggable.create("#spinner", { type: "rotation", throwProps: true });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable that particular feature, you need ThrowPropsPlugin which is a membership benefit of Club GreenSock. See details and sign up at https://greensock.com/club/. Once you're signed up, you can download the zip that contains all the bonus stuff and then just load the ThrowPropsPlugin JS file into your page and BOOM, that feature will be enabled in Draggable. Sorry if there was any confusion.